# Django annotate count unique user from 2 tables

Tags: django, django-annotate

Is it possible to do an annotate count on technically 2 different tables, but same FK?

Example:

```
queryset = ModelName.objects
.annotate(mileage_emp_count=Count('mileageclaim__user',distinct=True))
.annotate(general_emp_count=Count('expenseclaim__user', distinct=True))
```

For instance using this, is User A has a mileage and an expense claim, they will appear in both queries. So I will have result of 2 if i add them together.

What i need to do, is get a total of 1 unique user instead.

Is it possible without a lot of extra checks?

Comment: You could start filtering on both criteria then count distinct users int eh remaining rows

Comment: I need the whole dataset so cant per filter, and wanted to avoid extra queries if possible. So was hoping for something like this to exist, total_emp_count=Count('expenseclaim__user' OR IN 'mileageclaim__user', distinct=True)

Comment: When you use `count()`, anyway you create a query. So, you can use something like `df.filter(your conditions).count(what you have to count)`